# Why does the covariance matrix reduce to a scalar in this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, machine-learning

from [Machine Learning: A Probabilisic Perspective](https://doc.lagout.org/science/Artificial%20Intelligence/Machine%20learning/Machine%20Learning_%20A%20Probabilistic%20Perspective%20%5BMurphy%202012-08-24%5D.pdf) page 100 in this version.

[image: MLAPP equation 4.15]

How do we get from the far right hand side of 4.15 to 4.16? I don't see why the inverse of the covariance matrix can be reduced to become $\frac{1}{N}$...

Comment: The point is that $\hat{\mu}$ is independent of the covariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are solving the equation for a value of $\mu$ such that the derivative of the likelihood function with respect to $\mu$ is 0. The fact that $\Sigma$ is invertible means you can multiply on both sides by it. It isn't a scalar.

Comment: ok. I see what you are saying, but then where does the $\frac{1}{N}$ come from?

Comment: @deltaskelta From the fact that the sim contains $N$ copies of $\mu$.

Comment: Oh right..thanks